# Decomposition of a function as a sum

Tags: analysis

Let $f:I \times J\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a function of class $C^2$ in the open rectangle $I \times J \subset \mathbb R^2$. If $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}\equiv 0$, prove that there exist $\phi:I \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $\chi:J \rightarrow \mathbb R$ of class $C^2$ such that $f(x,y)=\phi(x)+\chi(y)$.

Solution:

Since $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left (\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right )=0$, then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ doesn't depend on $x$, i.e., $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=f(x_0,y)$, $x_0 = $ constant.

For a similar reason, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=f(x,y_0)$.

Now we define $\overline{\phi}:I \rightarrow \mathbb R;\overline{\phi}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}f(x,y_0)$ and $\overline \chi:J \rightarrow \mathbb R; \overline{\chi}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}f(x_0,y)$.

Then $f(x,y)=f(x,y)-f(x_0,y)+f(x_0,y)-f(x_0,y_0)+f(x_0,y_o)$. By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $f(x,y)=\int_{x_0}^{x}\frac{\partial f(s,y)}{\partial x}ds+\int_{y_0}^{y} \frac{\partial f(x_0,t)dt}{\partial y}+f(x_0,y_0) \Rightarrow f(x,y)=\int_{x_0}^{x} \overline{\phi}(s)ds+\int_{y_o}^{y}\overline{\chi}(t)dt +f(x_0,y_o) $.

If $\phi$ and $\chi$ are the primitives of $\overline{\phi}$ and $\overline{\chi}$, then

$f(x,y)= \phi(x)-\phi(x_0) +\chi(y) -\chi(y_0)+f(x_0,y_0)$. As you see, I didn't manage to get the result, so any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the first step is fine, but $f_y = a(y)$ for some $a$ rather than $f_y = f(x_0,y)$.
Otherwise, everything looks fine: you obtained the desired representation, the only thing you need to notice is that it concerns functions $\hat\phi(x) := \phi(x) - \phi(x_0) + f(x_0,y_0)$ and $\hat\psi(y) := \psi(y) - \psi(y_0)$.

Comment: Hello, Ilya! I didn't understand why $\hat\phi(x) := \phi(x) - \phi(x_0) + f(x_0,y_0)$ and $\hat\psi(y) := \psi(y) - \psi(y_0)$. Could you explain this step?

Comment: @Walterr: you were required to find *some* functions of $x$ and $y$ for the decomposition. It does not matter how they are denoted. In your solution, $\phi$ and $\psi$ are not the final answer, but you could use them to obtain the final answer as I wrote.